# simple function assign error python

Tags: python, sage

I have a question about Sage/Python, but I'm sure it's a very general CS question. I have a large system of N non-linear equations in N variables. Before I pass it off to a numerical solver, I try and let Sage simplify the equations using solve. When working through a simple example, I have the following: 'eqa' is a list of equations to solve in the variables x0, x1, w0, w1, etc. The following works just fine from the command line:

```
 j(x0,x1,w0,w1,y0,y1,z0,z1) = solve(eqa, var('x0 x1 w0 w1 y0 y1 z0 z1'))
```

(I'm trying to define the list of equations as a 'callable symbolic expression' (Sage) because the numerical optimization I use works better with these rather than normal def python functions.)

In any case, when I include this in a script and try to load it, I get the error:

```
     j(x0,x1,w0,w1,y0,y1,z0,z1) = solve(eqa, var('x0 x1 w0 w1 y0 y1 z0 z1'))
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I know I must be doing something wrong at the command line and its just working by some dumb luck. Or is special care needed when defining these callable symbolic expressions in a script? Thanks for any insight you can provide. Here is a link on the difference between these types of 'functions'

http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way of defining functions is Sage-specific, and forbidden by standard Python syntax.  My guess is that either (1) you're trying to run your script using Python, or (2) you're using Sage, but your filename ends with `.py` and so Sage is interpreting it as a Python file.

For example:

```
~/coding$ cat test.sage 
f(x, y) = 3*x+y
print f(3,4)

~/coding$ sage test.sage 
13
~/coding$ cp test.sage test.py
~/coding$ sage test.py
  File "test.py", line 1
    f(x, y) = 3*x+y
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
~/coding$ python test.py
  File "test.py", line 1
    f(x, y) = 3*x+y
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: (2) was exactly the problem. Thanks so much!